# Could there be any action taken against the contributors of Climate Change and Global Warming?

Tags: united-states, military, sanctions, climate-change

With the rising concern over Climate Change and Global Warming especially due to the IPCC report, could there be any sanctions or some kind of action taken by the UN or NATO against countries (and militaries like the US Military, which seems to be a significant contributor towards Climate Change)?

Source: [US Military](https://theconversation.com/us-military-is-a-bigger-polluter-than-as-many-as-140-countries-shrinking-this-war-machine-is-a-must-119269)

Comment: Could you explain the reason for the downvote? At least, it would help me to know what not to ask again.

Comment: How could someone take any action? There hasn't been any agreement against violation. I didn't vote though. I don't vote.

Comment: Like for example, could countries that have ratified the Kyoto Protocol impose some kind of sanctions against countries that haven't ratified the protocol and have proven to be a major source of GHG emissions i.e The US? Also, is there some kind of necessity that only when there is a broken agreement that some kind of actions are taken? Thanks!

Comment: @Aadhavan - The linked article says: *In fact, the United States insisted on an exemption for reporting military emissions in the 1997 Kyoto Protocol.* So no, sanctions for military emissions are not available through Kyoto.

Comment: That was just an example I gave, so I am interested in other possibilities. Although, I read in the same article or some other article that the loophole for military emissions has been closed due to the Paris Accord. Thanks for responding!

Comment: What action do you want them to take? Wouldn't taking action against those who have ratified the treaty discourage others from doing that? We want to encourage change not punish those that are trying and possibly keep others from even attempting to change.

Comment: What is the organization - "NATO"? Is it parallel to the UN in authority regarding matters or issues relating to the world? How about countries such as China and Russia?

Comment: @r13 - [North Atlantic Treaty Organization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NATO) and no, not parallel to the UN and not the world.

Comment: @RickSmith That's why I was questioning the justification of the line: "could there be any sanctions or some kind of action taken by the UN or **NATO** against countries.."

Comment: @r13 - The context of the statement suggest, to me, sanctions by NATO against its members like the US and its military. This based on inclusion of and statements in the linked article.

Comment: @RickSmith It could be the case, but lack of the words "against its own members (the US included)", it seems the UN and NATO both can decide to against the violating countries around the world, which is the function for the UN but NATO unless authorized by the world body.

Comment: *Ex post facto* laws are strictly forbidden in many countries, including the US. The US Congress can pass a new law that makes a formerly legal act illegal, but those who violated that new law in the past cannot be nailed for acts they conducted when those actions were not illegal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot of things **could** happen if there was widespread sentiment to do it. Once upon a time, slavery was legal. Then some nations banned it. Then the military forces of some countries [enforced that ban](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blockade_of_Africa), pretty much worldwide. Over decades and centuries, what was once normal business practice became universally banned, but it was a long and uneven process.

Right not I don't see such a sentiment developing for climate change. The most powerful countries are, per capita, the most siginifcant climate destroyers. Things might get interesting **if** the most powerful nations become [carbon-neutral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon_neutrality) some years from now and then take action against the remaining holdouts.

As to the downvotes, you are asking a hypothetical quite divorced from political reality. One might also ask if the moon is made of cheese, but that would not be an useful astronomy question. There is overwhelming evidence that it is made of rock.

Comment: Citation needed on the claim that the most powerful countries are, per capita, the most significant climate destroyers.  According to the latest data available on Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_carbon_dioxide_emissions_per_capita), the largest climate destroyers per capita seem to  be smaller, countries.  In particular, in the first chart, according to 2018 data, the highest "powerful" country on the list is Saudi Arabia in 11th place at 18.6 metric tons of carbon per capita; the top-ranked  Palau is almost 60 tons of carbon per capita.

Comment: In order to get 5 members of the G20 on the list (to pick a completely arbitrary cutoff point),  you have to count 21 places in the 2018 data in the first chart; those 5 members  are,  in order: Saudi Arabia, Australia, Canada/US (tied), and South Korea

Comment: @Ertai87, the US and Russia are both in the top decile for CO2.